# Where to save time and other values so I can read them after arduino powered down?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, memory

I need to save some values (and be able to update them frequently) that will stay there even after powering down the Arduino. (I didn't specifically choose any board yet, but UNO or Mega will be probably best for me).

(the values will be a short time informations)

Comment: How often do you need to write? EEPROM is usually ok but has limited write cycles. I usually recommend adding an external EERAM chip like the 47C16.

Comment: About every 1 minute or so.

Comment: That frequency would kill EEPROM after about 2-3 months.

Comment: That isnt really good. What about the flash memory?

Comment: A week. Take a look at the 47C16 chip from Microchip.

Comment: It depends on how much data you want to save. If you just want to save one set of data everytime, replacing the old data, you might be able to extend the lifetime of the EEPROM significantly through wear leveling (spreading the writes over a bigger span of memory, so that the individual memory cell gets written less frequently). Thats also, what SD cards do with their flash memory. Please give us a bit more context of what you are trying to do

Comment: If the 47C16 Majenko mentioned is interesting but you want more cycles and are willing to pay for it, there are SPI FRAM chips also.  I'm not aware of any in DIP, but you can hand solder an SOIC8 to a DIP adapter if needed.  There are probably a few prefab modules kicking around also.

Comment: Personally I use FRAM, fast and unlimited read and almost unlimited writes. They are available on breakout boards for a few bucks.

Comment: You might like to search for a solution that detects a coming power loss and save only in this case. This commonly adds some hardware to your circuit. -- Instead of serial (flash) EEPROM you can also consider battery backed SRAM, available with serial interfaces. Just make sure to check and change the battery regularly.

Comment: As stated in one above comment, If same structure of datas (not "too big"), and can save not "too fast", use files saved onto SD cards with time/date as name ...